# Microsoft Azure Active Directory - Cant Add App From App Directory - OpenID Connect-based Sign-on

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory

I have a purchased account of **Microsoft Azure portal**, but I cant add an Application from **Enterprise Application directory** specifically that Application who is having **single sign-on mode: OpenID Connect-based Sign-on**, it shows **Add button as disabled.**, however, i can add any other application who is having any type of single sign-on modes like SAML-based Sign-on or Password-based Sign-on
URL

- [screencast1](https://www.screencast.com/t/bCJgAXvVc)
- [screencast2](https://www.screencast.com/t/Sv8aQBSKG22)

is there setting anywhere that I have disabled unknowingly?

**PS** : its not only about one app, i can't add any live app whose SSO is openId connect, in screencast i have given an app just to show disability of add button. so its not about infonix specific an app its General.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Infolinx works with Azure AD. To get started, sign up for Infolinx using an account in your instance of Azure AD.

Suggest you to contact Infolinx, in case if you have any difficulties in sign up.

Comment: It is not only about infonix, i just gave an example of infonix , all apps who is having SSO : openID have add button disbled.

Comment: For all apps that support OpenID connect as the SSO protocol. You won't be able to add the app from the gallery as you do for SAML based apps. 

To provision the application to your Azure AD directory, you have to go to Infolinx sign in URL. Then, if it's the first time you sign in, you will receive a consent prompt. After you have consented, the app will be provisioned to your tenant.